# How to use this CSS font technique?

Tags: css, fonts

The header in mozilla lab's Bespin anouncement has a very nice antialized font put there with css (which is not a standard font). Anyone knows how did they do it?

**Bespin Embedded 0.6 released! Now in two great flavors.**

http://mozillalabs.com/bespin/2010/01/15/bespin-embedded-0-6-released-now-in-two-great-flavors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're using the @font-face directive.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MuseoSans";
    src: url(fonts/MuseoSans_500.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

Then you can simply use the `font-family` as you would in any other css rule. This is only supported by a few browsers, since it is CSS3.

ALA has a great article regarding CSS3 and font-face [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssatten).

Answer (score 1):

If you see at the css source code they define a new font-face with an external font-file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MuseoSans";
    src: url(fonts/MuseoSans_500.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

and then use the newly defined family in the css..

Answer (score 0):

Try [reading up on font-face](http://24ways.org/2009/spruce-it-up) and then head over to [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/).